# How to create Unity Catalog tables/views via Terraform?

Tags: terraform, databricks, terraform-provider-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

There are a [bunch](https://docs.databricks.com/data-governance/unity-catalog/create-views.html#create-a-view) of [pages](https://docs.databricks.com/data-governance/unity-catalog/create-tables.html#create-a-managed-table) in the documentation that mention tables and views can be created via Terraform:

> You can also create a managed table by using the [Databricks Terraform provider](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/terraform/index.html) and [databricks_table](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/table).

But those links to `databricks_table` and `databricks_view` that lead to the TF provider documentation seems to say that these resources are no longer provided:

> Page Not Found: This documentation page doesn't exist for version 1.14.3  of the databricks provider.

Are the Databricks docs out of date? Then is there another way to create Unity Catalog tables or views via TF?

My concrete problem is I have some configuration data in Terraform files that needs to be used to create a specific view. The TF configuration is obviously not accessible from the Databricks workspace so I can't create the view from the workspace, hence I'm trying to create the view via TF where the configuration data is readily available.

I already create via TF the catalogs, schemas and everything else to set up Databricks.

If tables and views cannot be created via TF, is there some other way that data defined in TF files can be exposed to the Databricks workspace? Then I could create my views in the workspace environment (via Python or SQL).

Answer (score 2):

Previous versions of Databricks Terraform provider had the `databricks_table` resource that was used to create tables & views. But it was implemented on a top of API that didn't make into the UC release because of problems with tables initialization or something like that. So this resource was pulled off from provider. There is a [work in progress](https://github.com/databricks/terraform-provider-databricks/pull/2213) on implementing `databricks_sql_table` resource that will use a cluster to create/update tables & views.  Hopefully it will be released soon.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through Databrick's Terraform provider issues in GitHub, the developers say that creating tables in Unity Catalog via Terraform is [discouraged](https://github.com/databricks/terraform-provider-databricks/issues/1624#issuecomment-1256448911):

> there are quite a few gaps/edge cases with the tables API, hence customers should not use the API or Terraform to create/manage Unity Catalog tables & views at the moment.

They [used to offer](https://github.com/databricks/terraform-provider-databricks/issues/2009#issuecomment-1432971039) the `databricks_table` and `databricks_view` resources, but removed them because they weren't working properly:

> For Create & Update, there are many cases where it does not work, hence they remain undocumented and unsupported. Because of this, the `databricks_table` resource is hidden from the doc, even though the code remains available for customers who have previously created tables via Terraform.

And forgot to remove references to these resources in their documentation as I showed in my question.

Ultimately, the answer is to create tables/views via a Databricks Job. (And data from Terraform can be communicated to the job by using Kubernetes secrets.)

PS: There are a few more [ideas](https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D58Y0000ABW4MiSQL/how-to-create-unity-catalog-tablesviews-via-terraform) on the Databricks board.